# How to set up mouse second and third button?

Tags: macos, mouse

In my office we work with mac, I used to have a regular mouse but it is not working anymore so I am now using a apple mouse.

The problem with the apple mouse is that it lacks of certains functionalities, such as right-click or middle-button drag scrolling.

I want to enable right-click on the right-click of the mouse. (I find it pretty uncomfortable to ctrl+click when I could just right click with the mouse, which has that button.) I tried setting it up in system settings -> Mouse and select secondary button, but it does not work. It is just the same as the primary button.

I also want to enable scrolling by keeping pressed the middle button of the mouse (3rd button). Can I do this?

Thanks a lot buddies.

Comment: Needs more info - what Mac, what OS, what Mouse? The answers will all be "open system prefs > mouse"… but the specifics will be different.

Comment: I have OS X Yosemite in a MacBook Pro 2011. The mouse is an oldie mac mouse, it has two buttons at the sides, leftclick, rightlclick, and the scrollable ball which is also clickable. I tried configuring in system prefs > mouse, but still the right click (configured as secondary button) will not open any menu when rightclicking (the menu that shows up with ctrl click)

Comment: ahhh, that one… no physical buttons on top, just a tiny scroll-ball? Mine lasted a week before it went in a drawer ;-) You need to take your finger off the left 'button' before the right will register - truly dozy idea.

Comment: @Tetsujin No, it is not that one. It has two physical buttons on the top besides the tiny scrollball. They are not visible , but I can click them. It is not touch. This is the mouse http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/272035548394?item=272035548394&lgeo=1&vectorid=229466&rmvSB=true

Answer (score 1):

I found how to do it. It is not the most comfortable way having both, if anyone knows a work-around I'll be thankfull.

I had to set secondary button in the tiny scroll-ball , that way it works. And about the drag scrolling, i am using smart scroll software, but I also have to set it up in secondary button , and it also works with the tiny scrollball click.